# Javascript check if all values in an object array are empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array like below.

```
let report = [
  {0: { error1: '', error2: ''}},
  {1: { error1: '', error2: ''}}
]
```

I want to check if all the error values are empty.
Then based on that result I will enable or disable a button. If all the error values are empty, then the save button will be enabled.
How can I achieve that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check it's syntax `report`,  haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```js
let report = [
  { 0: { error1: "", error2: "" } },
  { 1: { error1: "", error2: "" } },
];

const testToSeeAllErrorsAreEmpty = report.every((item) =>
  Object.values(item).every((objContainsErrors) =>
    Object.values(objContainsErrors).every((error) => !error)
  )
);

console.log("testToSeeAllErrorsAreEmpty: ", testToSeeAllErrorsAreEmpty)
```

Answer (score 0):

This recursive function checks if an object (or array) is empty, if not iterates it's properties, and check if they are empty. If the a property is an object (or array), the function checks if it's empty and so on. Only if all leaves are empty, the function returns `true`.

```js
const checkEmptyLeaves = o => {
  if(_.isObject(o)) return _.isEmpty(o) || _.every(o, checkEmptyLeaves);
  
  return _.isEmpty(o);
};

const report1 = [
  { 0: { error1: "", error2: "" } },
  { 1: { error1: "", error2: "" } },
];

const report2 = [
  { 0: { error1: "", error2: { message: "some message" } } },
  { 1: { error1: "", error2: "" } },
];

console.log(checkEmptyLeaves(report1));
console.log(checkEmptyLeaves(report2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```